# Como capturar atributo class com Cheerio?

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

Estou estudando Web Scrapping com Cheerio e Request. Estou tendo dificuldade ao tentar capturar o atributo class no site da Amazon que contém uma lista de div e não está retornando nada.

```
var Crawler = {
    request : null,
    cheerio : null,
    init : function(){
        Crawler.request = require('request');
        Crawler.cheerio = require('cheerio');
        Crawler.getProducts();
    },
    getProducts: function(){
        Crawler.request('https://www.amazon.com.br/s?k=notebook&__mk_pt_BR=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&crid=13P0U6JH9AMHS&sprefix=%2Caps%2C416&ref=nb_sb_ss_i_1_1', function(err, res, body){
            if(err) console.log('Error: ' + err);

            var $ = Crawler.cheerio.load(body);

            $('div.s-result-list.s-search-results.sg-row div').each(function(){
                console.log("capturou");
            });
        });
    }
};
Crawler.init();
```

O que estou fazendo de errado ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Falta informar o atributo `gzip` no seu `request`:

```
Crawler.request({
  gzip: true,
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://www.amazon.com.br/s?k=notebook&__mk_pt_BR=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&crid=13P0U6JH9AMHS&sprefix=%2Caps%2C416&ref=nb_sb_ss_i_1_1',
}, function (err, res, body) {
  // Execucação ...
});
```

---

> [`gzip`](https://github.com/request/request)
>
> if `true`, add an `Accept-Encoding` header to request compressed content encodings from the server (if not already present) and decode supported content encodings in the response.

Em tradução livre:

> Se `true`, adiciona um cabeçalho `Accept-Encoding` para requisitar o conteúdo comprimido do servidor (se ainda não estiver presente) e decodifica conteúdos de codificação suportadas na resposta.

---

Fora isso seu código não está seguindo as boas práticas para o `Node.js`, mas sem saber a versão que você está utilizando (e considerando que não faz parte da resposta) é inviável sugerir mudanças.